# Segmentation fault when send HTTP request and get response in C

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, client

I made a client socket that connect to a server. Then I wanna send HTTP Request to it.

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.google.com\r\n
\r\n
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MAX 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *host;
    strcpy(host, argv[1]);

    char *request = "GET ";
    strcat(request, argv[3]);
    strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
    strcat(request, argv[2]);
    strcat(request, "\r\n\r\n");

    char *response;

    int port;
    port = atoi(argv[2]);

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
            perror("Failed to create socket!");
            exit(1);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    struct hostent *server;
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) perror("Failed to get host name!");

    memcpy(&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0){
            perror("Failed to connect!");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(request, MAX, stdin) != NULL){
            send(sockfd, request, strlen(request), 0);
            if(recv(sockfd, response, MAX, 0) == 0){
                    perror("Failed to recieve!");
                    exit(1);
            }

            printf("Response:/n");
            fputs(response, stdout);
    }
```

When I run it, it got a segmentation fault. Then I use GDB to trace it.

```
#0  strcmp () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:132
#1  0x00007ffff7deb1a5 in _dl_name_match_p (name=0x4004e9 "libc.so.6",     map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8) at dl-misc.c:289
#2  0x00007ffff7de402f in do_lookup_x (new_hash=new_hash@entry=479433942, old_hash=old_hash@entry=0x7fffffffe950, 
result=result@entry=0x7fffffffe960, scope=<optimized out>, i=<optimized out>, i@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=1, 
skip=skip@entry=0x0, undef_map=undef_map@entry=0x7ffff7ffe1c8) at dl-lookup.c:462
#3  0x00007ffff7de4961 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x40056b "strcat", undef_map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8, 
ref=ref@entry=0x7fffffffea18, symbol_scope=0x7ffff7ffe520, version=0x7ffff7ff9a10, type_class=type_class@entry=1, flags=1, 
skip_map=skip_map@entry=0x0) at dl-lookup.c:737
#4  0x00007ffff7de9527 in _dl_fixup (l=<optimized out>, reloc_arg=<optimized out>) at ../elf/dl-runtime.c:111
#5  0x00007ffff7df04d5 in _dl_runtime_resolve () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S:45
#6  0x0000000000400b18 in main ()
```

The error message really made me confused. Where exactly I made mistakes?

Comment: `host` and `request` do not point to a writable memory buffer. You cannot use `strcpy`, `strcat` or any other write operation on it. You need to allocate memory using `malloc` for example.

Comment: And be carefully with using `argv[2]` argument, because: `strcat(request, argv[2])` and `port = atoi(argv[2]);`.
So `argv[2]` is host or `argv[2]` is port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *request = "GET ";
/* you can't do this */
strcat(request, argv[3]);
strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
strcat(request, argv[2]);
strcat(request, "\r\n\r\n");
```

As `request` points to constant string, you cannot append more characters to it. You need to allocate more memory for it and then append more strings to it.

Similarly for `response`. Allocate memory for it before reading data into it.

In - general add

```
request = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
response = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
```

Then

```
strcpy(request, "GET ");
strcat(request, argv[3]);
strcat(request, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
strcat(request, argv[2]);
strcat(request, "\r\n\r\n");
```

Better to use `strncat` etc function to be safe.

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful.